# Probability mass function of integer-valued r.v. without inversion theorem

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Given $Z$ is an integer-valued r.v., Its mass function is:

$$P(Z=z) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\exp(-itz)}{2\pi}\times\phi_Z(t)\;dt, \quad z\in\mathbb{Z}$$

I am clear about how to show this by using inversion, but still have no idea about the method without general inversion theorem. Anyone may give some aid?

Comment: Here $$\phi_Z(t) = \mathbb E\left[e^{itz}\right] = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} e^{itn}\mathbb P(Z=n), $$ correct?

Comment: @Math1000 I forgot to clarify it. Yes.

Comment: Use Fubini to exchange sum and integral... and rejoice.

Comment: @Did Thanks. I solved it using Fubini.